# How to render different pages based on the user type in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to oracle apex and having trouble finding resources on how to do it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the same page *differently* to each user, you'd then use the "Server-side condition" whose type is a function that returns Boolean, e.g.

```
return f_app_type(:APP_USER) in ('MANAGER', 'ANALYST');
```

which would render that element (region, item, whatever) only to users who are either managers or analysts, while other users wouldn't see it.

---

Or, if you wanted to navigate users to different pages, then you could use a branch. As it also offers the Server-side condition, you'd basically use the same principle as above and redirect each user to their own page.